# Laravel : login failed after changing password on API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

New to JWT and i want to simply change my password after that i try to log in it is not working.

My update password function code :

```
public function resetPassword(ResetPasswordRequest $request, JWTAuth $JWTAuth)
{
    $password = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user = User::where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
    if(!$user) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Credential do not match",
            'status_code' => 403,
        ]);
    }
    if($user) {
        $user->password = $password;
        $user->save();
    }
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Your password has been changed successfully','status_code' => 204]);
}
```

This function working fine after i try to log in it is return `$token` null.

My login controller code :

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request, JWTAuth $JWTAuth)
{

    $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
    try {
        $token = Auth::guard()->attempt($credentials);
        if(!$token) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => "Email and password do not match",
                'status_code' => 403,
            ]);
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->last_login = Carbon::now();
        $user->save();
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->UserDeviceData()->firstOrCreate([
            'device_id' => $request->device_id
        ]);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => "Internal server error",
            'status_code' => 500,
        ]);
    }
    return (new UserTransformer)->transform($user);
}
```

On `user` model :

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
}
```

What is the problem ? It is a right way to do a change password ?

Comment: use bycrypt `$password = bcrypt($request->password);`

Comment: @Sohel0415 not working.

Comment: try removing the function of user model

Comment: @Sohel0415 ok but when a new user signup then ?

Comment: share how you are calling `login` function ?

Comment: then you can set this manually there too, i would suggest first make a working code, then you can restructure your code according to your need

Comment: @Sohel0415 `public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }` still not working

Comment: change this code `$user->password = $password;
        $user->save();` to `$user->update(['password'=>$request->password])`

Comment: @Sohel0415 it is working now.

Comment: @Javed great, hope you understand the point

Answer (score 0):

While resetting your password, you are hashing your password two times one in `resetPassword` function and second in `setPasswordAttribute`so you need to replace

this
 `$password = Hash::make($request->password)`;

with this
 `$password = $request->password;`

in your `resetPassword` function